# How should I construct LIKE queries using multiple values

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a question about searching a product (table) just by one or more letters and come up the columns that I want (name, description and type) but I have a problem on using the keyword. I know it should be a string but i can't figure out a way to do it.
Right now i have this

```
@app.route('/product/<keyword>', methods=['GET'])
def product_search(kw):
    logger.info('GET /product/<keyword>')

    logger.debug(f'keyword: {kw}')

    conn = db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()

    try:
        cur.execute('SELECT id, type, name, price from product where name like s% or type like s% or description like %s', (kw,))
        rows = cur.fetchall()

        row = rows[0]

        logger.debug('GET /product/{keyword} - parse')
        logger.debug(row)
        content = {'id': int(row[0]), 'type': row[1], 'name': row[2], 'price': row[3], 'description': row[5]}

        response = {'status': StatusCodes['success'], 'results': content}

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        logger.error(f'GET /product/{keyword} - error: {error}')
        response = {'status': StatusCodes['internal_error'], 'results': str(error)}

    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

    return flask.jsonify(response)
```

And I also wanted to know if I could do

```
cur.execute('SELECT id, type, name, price from product where name like s% or type like s% or description like s%
%s', (kw,))
```

a way to basically execute the program but doing it for example using the letter c to search a product like coke or something

```
 'SELECT id, type, name, price from product where name like '%c' or type like '%c' or description like '%c%'
```

in other words I want it for the name and type to search by the first letter and the description by the middle of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to interpolate values into SQL queries in Python is to use [parameter substitution](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), as you are already doing, for example:

```py
values = ('Alice', 'Bob')
cur.execute("""SELECT name FROM tbl WHERE name = %s OR name = %s""", values)
```

The values are correctly quoted by the connector to minimise the risk of errors and of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Using string formatting techniques to do this is error prone and not recommended.

To handle values for `LIKE` queries, you need to append or prepend the "%" characters to the values, like this:

```py
values = (kw + '%',)
cur.execute("""SELECT id, type, name, price from product where name like %s""", values)
```

If you want to use the same value in multiple places, you can use a dictionary of values instead of a tuple:

```py
values = {'kw': kw + '%', 'kw2': '%' + kw + '%'} 
cur.execute("""SELECT id, type, name, price from product where name like %(kw)s or type like %(kw)s or description like %(kw2)s""", values)
```

Note that it's OK to build the values themselves using string formatting, like this

```py
values = (f'{kw}%',)
cur.execute(sql, values)
```

but it is not OK to use string formatting to place the values into the query itself:

```py
# Not OK
cur.execute(f"""SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name = {kw}""")
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the same name in function input parameters as in url, it you do so it will be str already:

```
@app.route('/product/<keyword>', methods=['GET'])
def product_search(keyword):
    print(type(keyword)) # <class 'str'>
```

Comment: i just think that this part is incorrect becuase a friend of mine told me it should be a string and i don't know how to do it @app.route('/product/<keyword>', methods=['GET'])

Comment: @fmdgaspar indeed missed one thing, updated answer